# Jenkinsfile Switch case with contains is throwing CpsCallableInvocation error

Tags: jenkins, grails, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to write a jenkins file with a switch case, where I am trying to use string operations in case. In a regular groovy it is working fine but in JenkinsFile it is throwing errors. What am I missing?

*Code*

```
        switch (env.UPSTREAM)
        {
            case { it.contains("SDK") }:
                //do something
                break
            case { it.contains("sample") }:
                //do something
                break
        }
```

*Error*

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: CpsCallableInvocation{methodName=call, call=com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef@47e13b68, receiver=org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@3d8cf0c6, arguments=[asjkndakjsd_sample]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins uses Groovy CPS to run pipeline scripts, you can read about it [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches).  It's kind of confusing but basically you can't use some of the more complicated groovy functions/commands.

A way to get around this is to use the `@NonCPS` annotation.  You have to create a function outside of your pipeline with that `@NonCPS` annotation.  But in your case you could probably just use simple `if` statements instead of the `switch`.  For example just create a new variable `def upStream = env.UPSTREAM`  then check each case:

```
if (upStream.contains("SDK"))
{
    // do something
}
else if (upStream.contains("sample"))
{
    // do something
}
```